# Newly installed kernels won't boot - what am I doing wrong? Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, boot, kernel

I've been trying to install an updated kernel on my fresh Ubuntu Gnome 13.04 installation, mainly because it purportedly fixes the display brightness issue on my Dell XPS 13 FHD.

I'm following the guides on ubuntuhandbook, such as this one:

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/09/install-upgrade-kernel-3-11-2-ubuntu-linux-mint/

I follow the steps (running update-grub2 at the end to be sure) and it goes fine.  The kernels all show up in the Grub menu.  However, when I pick any kernel other than the included 3.8.x, it gets stuck on "Loading Linux  ..." and never proceeds to the ramdisk step, and never boots.

I tried this with 3.10.13, 3.11, 3.11.2 and the same thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I usually compile the kernel myself, but at the end I run  `sudo grub-mkconfig > grub_config` and then  `sudo mv grub_config /boot/grub/grub.cfg`  and maybe cp that old grub config for a backup. I doubt this would be the problem, maybe something to do with the kernels you are wgetting. Are they in your /boot folder? And is a proper config there for them as well?

Comment: I discovered that if I disabled Secure Boot on my machine and enabled the 'Load Legacy ROM' option, all of the kernels would boot fine.  (EFI is still technically enabled, from what I can tell).  Do I need to do something that somehow enables the kernels to boot with secure boot?

Comment: http://kroah.com/log/blog/2013/09/02/booting-a-self-signed-linux-kernel/    
It looks like there are some flags you can put in, they are here on the website. Comment back if this works, I have not had to work around secure boot yet but it looks as if that might be the future for most computers...